# temp mark off some targets in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I wish to compile partial targets which is **$(APPS)** but excluding targets in **$(OFF)** in the makefile:

```
APPS = a b c d e f g
OFF = d e

all: $(APPS)

partial: $(APPS) - $(OFF)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just take a slightly different approach:

```
ON = a b c f g
OFF = d e
APPS = $(ON) $(OFF)

partial: $(ON)
```

But if this is too simplistic for your needs, there is a [`filter-out` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions) that can provide the exact operation you want:

```
      objects=main1.o foo.o main2.o bar.o
      mains=main1.o main2.o
      $(filter-out $(mains),$(objects))
```

I think re-writing your example in this format would be:

```
APPS = a b c d e f g
OFF = c d

partial: $(filter-out $(APPS),$(OFF))
```